# WordPress Previous and Next Button Exclude Multiple Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a WordPress blog where posts have multiple categories selected. I am using a "Previous Post" and "Next Post" button at the bottom of each post. I would like the next or previous post to be in the same category-- wordpress allows for this paramater in the `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` functions, however it gets complicated when you have more than one category-- it chooses the category with the lowest category ID, which leads to inconsistent post navigation.

What I want to do is get the post category from the permalink, which is formatted as /%category%/%postname% then get an array of all categories, remove the current post category from that array, then exclude that array from the next and previous post link, effectively leaving only the current category (as dictated by the permalink). For example, if the permalink is "myurl.com/music/september-guitar-post", I want to exclude all categories *except* music from the previous and next post links.

Here is the code I'm using (that doesn't seem to be functioning how I want it to):

```
function remove_item_by_value($array, $val = '', $preserve_keys = true) {
    if (empty($array) || !is_array($array)) return false;
    if (!in_array($val, $array)) return $array;

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $val) unset($array[$key]);
    }

    return ($preserve_keys === true) ? $array : array_values($array);
}

$link = get_permalink();
$link = explode('/',$link);
$currentCat = $link[3];
$currentCat = get_category_by_slug( $currentCat );
$currentCatId = $currentCat->term_id;
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $catList[] = $category->term_id;
}

$exclude = remove_item_by_value($catList, $currentCatId);
$exclude = implode(' and ',$exclude);

previous_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post', TRUE, $exclude);
next_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post', TRUE, $exclude);
```

All the code works until trying to use the $exclude string as a parameter in the next/prev post link functions. Upon further testing, simply trying to exclude a single category does not seem to work (`next_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post', TRUE, '3')` ) for example. Can anyone confirm that this code actually functions as the documentation says it does?

How do I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note all **four** places where you input your categories to be excluded.
the example id's are id=10 id=20 id=30

```
//Exclude Categories From Previous/Next
function custom_prev_next_posts() { 
global $thesis_design; 

if (is_single() && $thesis_design->display['posts']['nav']) { 
    $previous = get_previous_post(FALSE,'10,20,30'); 
    $next = get_next_post(FALSE,'10,20,30'); 
    $previous_text = apply_filters('thesis_previous_post', __('Previous entry: ',  'thesis')); #filter 
    $next_text = apply_filters('thesis_next_post', __('Next entry: ', 'thesis'));   #filter 

    if ($previous || $next) { 
        echo "\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"prev_next post_nav\">\n"; 

        if ($previous) { 
            if ($previous && $next) 
                $add_class = ' class="previous"'; 

            echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<p$add_class>$previous_text"; 
            previous_post_link('%link', '%title',FALSE,'10,20,30'); 
            echo "</p>\n"; 
        } 

        if ($next) { 
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>$next_text"; 
            next_post_link('%link', '%title',FALSE,'10,20,30'); 
            echo "</p>\n"; 
        } 

        echo "\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n"; 
    } 
  } 
} 

add_action('wp_hook_after_content', 'custom_prev_next_posts'); 
remove_action('wp_hook_after_content', 'wp_prev_next_posts');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`next_page_link`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link), you need to pass the excluded categories as a string containing the ids separated by `" and "`:

```
$exclude = implode(' and ', $exclude);
next_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post', TRUE, $exclude);
previous_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post', TRUE, $exclude);
```

If the documentation is not lying, this should work.

Comment: I was just re-reading the next_page_link codex as you posted this and did exactly what you wrote above, but there are still posts whose next/prev post link goes to categories other than the one in their permalink. I've echoed out the $exclude variable and it contains in the correct format the excluded categories "3 and 864 and 4 and 13 and 1"

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using $category->term_id as opposed to $category->cat_id? I have never used term id's in WP, but if I was going to tackle this I would probably use the cat_id as a first attempt.

Comment: Yea-- term_id echoes out correctly what it should be echoing.

Comment: Sure the term_id is the categroy id if the category of the term is category. ;) Anyway, are some of the categories childcategories of another one?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation below, it appears the exclude parameter must be a string (not an array) of the form "1 and 2 and 3" where 1, 2, 3 are example category IDs. Looks like you need to build this string from the array you are currently trying to use as the argument.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link